# Передвижение спрайта в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Я делаю простую программу, которая на нажатие стрелок будет перемещать картинку. Мне нужно,что бы спрайт двигался во время того, как зажата стрелка. Проблема в том, что сейчас если я нажимаю на стрелку спрайт движется один раз, и не реагирует на зажатие клавиши. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
import pygame
import os


def load_image(name, colorkey=None):
    fullname = os.path.join('data', name)
    try:
        image = pygame.image.load(fullname)
    except pygame.error as message:
        print('Cannot load image:', name)
        raise SystemExit(message)

    image = image.convert_alpha()
    if colorkey is not None:
        if colorkey is -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0, 0))
        image.set_colorkey(colorkey)
    return image


pygame.init()
size = width, height = 501, 501
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

hero_image = load_image("bomb.png")

hero = pygame.sprite.Sprite(all_sprites)
hero.image = hero_image
hero.rect = hero.image.get_rect()
all_sprites.add(hero)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # при закрытии окна
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            f = event.key
            if event.key == 273:
                hero.rect.top -= 10
            if event.key == 274:
                hero.rect.top += 10
            if event.key == 275:
                hero.rect.left += 10
            if event.key == 276:
                hero.rect.left -= 10
    screen.fill((0, 0, 78))
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы двигать объект всё время, пока нажата стрелка, надо создать 4 переменные, под названиями "left, up, right, down" и присвоить каждой из них значение false. Потом в цикле `for event in pygame.event.get()` проверять:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == K_UP:
        up = true
    if event.key == K_DOWN:
        down = true
    if event.key == K_RIGHT:
        right = true
    if event.key == K_LEFT:
        left = true

if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        up = false
    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        down = false
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        right = false
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        left = false
```

Затем в цикле `while running` проверять значения переменных "left, up, right, down", если у них значение true, то двигать объект hero в определённом направлении.